# Conditional MySQL query using LAST_DAY function

Tags: mysql

I try to construct a SELECT query to pull monthly data from a daily dataset that updates every day.

Here's a preamble:
I have stock price data at daily steps.
I want to extract prices at the end of every month.

For now, I use

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(date) AS date
     , FORMAT(close_price, 2) AS price 
  FROM company_data.ticker 
 GROUP 
    BY LAST_DAY(date);
```

However, this query has a flaw.

For the current unfinished month, it pulls the last available price value and places it against the last day of the month, e.g., for March, the query takes yesterday's price and associates it with 2021-03-31.

And so I want to query the DB so that it selects prices of the last day of each finished month and the price of the last available day of the current unfinished month and its corresponding date.

Thank you very much.

Below is the reproducible example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company_data.ticker 
(date DATE NOT NULL UNIQUE
, closePrice DECIMAL(12,6) NULL);

INSERT INTO company_data.ticker (date, closePrice) VALUES 
('2021-02-10', 99),
('2021-02-12', 96),
('2021-02-20', 98), 
('2021-02-28', 95),
('2021-03-01', 90), 
('2021-02-20', 91), 
('2021-02-24', 100);
```

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, man. Next time I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in another ticket: `SELECT * FROM company_data.ticker WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM company_data.ticker GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date));`
Thank you, everyone

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery that returns the last day of each month:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ticker t1
WHERE t1.date = (
  SELECT MAX(t2.date)
  FROM ticker t2
  WHERE LAST_DAY(t2.date) = LAST_DAY(t1.date)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=51a1664723edd62490e920a99d025f24).

Comment: Thank you, forpas. However, I've just realized that using `LAST_DAY` is wrong. This function returns the last CALENDAR date of each month, whereas I need to get the last date of the month in the dataset, which is not always the last calendar date. I found a solution in another ticket: `SELECT * FROM company_data.ticker WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM company_data.ticker GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date));`. Thank you anyway for your support.

Comment: @tumanoff this is what MAX(t2.date) in my query does. The LAST_DAY() function I use is not there to return the last date of each month. Did you try my query?

Comment: I did, and it returns the correct result. However, the query you'd suggested took significantly more time to process than the one I found - 22 sec against 0.094 sec

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, it will select the last day of month for all previous months and today for the current month.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LAST_DAY(t1.date) AS date
    ,FORMAT((SELECT t2.closePrice FROM ticker t2 WHERE MONTH(t2.date) = MONTH(t1.date) AND YEAR(t2.date) = YEAR(t1.date) ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1), 2) AS price
  FROM ticker t1
  WHERE month(t1. date) < month(curdate())
UNION
SELECT curdate() AS date
    ,FORMAT((SELECT t4.closePrice FROM ticker t4 WHERE MONTH(t4.date) = MONTH(t3.date) AND YEAR(t4.date) = YEAR(t3.date) ORDER BY t4.date DESC LIMIT 1), 2) AS price
  FROM ticker t3
  WHERE month(date) = month(curdate())
ORDER BY date;
```